# Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x = a$, and $f(a)\neq g(a)$, then $\max\{f, g\}$ and $\min\{f, g\}$ are differentiable at $x=a$

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ and  $g$ are differentiable at $x = a$, and  $f(a)\neq g(a)$, then  $\max\{f, g\}$ and $\min\{f, g\}$ are differentiable at $x=a$. Does this still hold  if $f(a) = g(a)$?

Comment: For your final question,  consider the case where $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ when $x=0$

Comment: This problem can be solved combining the following ideas: (1) Since $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x=a$, then they are also continuous at that point. (2) If the continuous function $f-g$ satisfies the inequality $f(a)-g(a)>0$, then in some neighborhood of $a$  the inequality $f(x)-g(x)>0$ is also satisfied. This gives that inside that neighborhood $f(x)=\max(f(x),g(x))$. (3) Is two functions are equal in a neighborhood of a point, then their differentiability at that point is the same. So, since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then so will be $\max(f(x),g(x))$. Other cases are similar.

Comment: @Henry . I posted my A before reading your comment.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet no problem

Comment: Thanks, my problem is the second part i need use lateral limits

Answer (score 2):

If $f,g$ are differentiable at $a$ then $f,g$ are continuous at $a$ so $f-g$ is continuous at $a$ so if (WLOG) $f(a)-g(a)>0$ then there is an open interval $J$ with $a\in J,$ such that  $f-g>0$ on $J$ so for all $x'\in J$ we have $\max (f(x'),g(x'))=f(x')$ and  $\min (f(x'),g(x'))=g(x').$

If $f(a)=g(a)$ the proposition may fail. E.g. if $a=0$ and $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x.$ Then  $\max (f(x),g(x))=|x|$ and  $\min (f(x),g(x))=-|x|,$ neither of which is differentiable at $x=0.$